# Bubble sort code in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, drjava

I still can't get this right. The code in the bubble sort is incorrect. How can I get this right? What should I change or add to get the correct results? Thanks in advance. :)

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HomeWork {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int choice;
        int e;

        Random t = new Random();
        for (e = 1; e <= 5; e++) {
            System.out.println(t.nextInt(1000));
        }
        System.out.println(" \n1: BUBBLE SORT ");
        System.out.println(" 2: SELECTION SORT ");
        System.out.println(" 3: QUICK SORT ");
        System.out.println(" Choose a number from 1-3 ");
        choice= s.nextInt();

        if(choice == 1) {
            System.out.print("You chose BUBBLE sort!");
            int temp, q, w;
            for(int i=0;i<w-1;i++) { //I think there is something wrong here in my bubble sort code. 
                       // What should I add or change to make this correct?
                for(int j=0;j<w-1-i;j++) {
                    if(q[j]>q[j+1]) {
                        temp = q[j];
                        q[j] = q[j+1];
                        q[j+1] = temp;
                        System.out.println(q[i]+""); // What should I change here to print the correct results?
                    } else if(choice == 2) {
                        System.out.print("You chose SELECTION sort!");
                    } else if(choice == 3) {
                        System.out.println("You chose QUICK sort!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Not in the choices!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am still just a beginner. Please please help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: At very least you should format code nicely when presenting it to public. While editing the post consider removing all "all wrong"/"new here"/"thank you" text as it does not provide any additional information.

Comment: Looping is correct but variables `q and w` are not initialised with any values and you need one more loop to print the sorted array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a[] = { 1, 5, 100, 40, 80, 50 };

    int length = a.length;
    int temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < length - i; j++) {
            if (a[j - 1] > a[j]) {
                temp = a[j - 1];
                a[j - 1] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Like the guy commented above, this the bubble sorting algorithm, and the guy above that, your Variable (w) is wrong, all wrong, and as a tip in the future, post the error, with the code, that's probably why you got a downvote and or because this is pretty simple.

Also forgive me, but i dont have eclipse, and am now coding in C++, but this should work

```
int x[] = new int[5]
Random t = new Random();
for (e = 1; e <= 5; e++) {
    x[e] = t.nextInt(1000); // you didn't even assign any variables to sort, that's one problem, you just printed them.
} // and idk how you get random int's in java, but if this doesn't work, just make your own random int generator.
  // There's LOTS of better ones than the one your using now.

int temp, q, w;

for(int i=0;i< 5;i++) { 
    for(int j=0;j<5-i;j++) {
        if(q[j]>q[j+1]) {
            temp = q[j-1];
            q[j-1] = q[j];
            q[j] = temp;
        } 
        // Add 'else ifs' here
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // and this will print the results
    System.out.print(q[i] + " ");
}
```

This should work, idk, not really experienced in java >.>, and btw there are tons of books that teach algorithm's, you should first look through your code really well, because of it's a simply mistake like now, these people on stack overflow aren't merciful, there all experience programmer that are really hard on you, but they are smart. (like me :D)

[EDIT] -btw, just merge this with your code, but here are some useful sites.
for random int's - http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=62
for bubble sort  - http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/bubble-sort-algorithm-in-java-code-example/

Comment: Oh, btw I just noticed your using DRjava or whatever that is, Eclipse IDE is alot better, it can find errors without building, and a way better IDE in most ways (and most popular), and if you do decide to get it, if you look up tutorials, look at the recent ones, even if they dont have alot of views on youtube. Also theres a way better help community/forums.

Comment: Thank you for your help. :) I am still a student that's why I can't understand java that much. But really, thank you so much for your kindness. :D

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you have not defined `q` or `w`--presumably you want them to be the array of numbers and its length. Furthermore, because your bubble sort does not automatically detect when the list has been sorted and stop then, it is more like a combined bubble/selection sort.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BubbleSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a[] = { 1, 5, 100, 40, 80, 50 };

        int length = a.length;
        int temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < length - i; j++) {
                if (a[j - 1] > a[j]) {
                    temp = a[j - 1];
                    a[j - 1] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with this code, hopefully nothing ;). It's just not answering the OP's question about **his** code - actually it's not answering **any** question. It's pretty much a random code snippet... (BTW I'm not your downvoter.)

Comment: @jangroth No issue, I think my fault i should figure out what was problem in OP's code instead of provide Bubble sort code.In future i will be take care these points.